# Marginal Distribution of Exponential Mixture Model

Tags: bayesian, exponential-distribution, marginal-distribution, integral, finite-mixture-model

I am currently trying to marginalize over the scale parameter in a mixture distribution of exponential pdfs, but I do not trust my result. Let me show you my steps:

**Probability Density Function**

The pdf for my exponential mixture distribution is given by:

$$ prob(t|\{a_j\},\{\tau_j\})=\sum_j a_j \cdot 1/\tau_j \cdot \exp(-t/\tau_j)$$

It describes the probability of observing an event (i.e. a radioactive decay) at time $t\in [0,\infty)$, given the scale parameters $\tau_j$ and the relative contributions $a_j$ of different decay components. By normalization we require $\sum_j a_j =1$. Futhermore let $j=1,...,N$, so that we have $N$ distinct components

**Marginalization Integral**

To get rid of the scale parameters I carried out the marginalization like this:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
prob(t|\{a_j\})&=&\int d\tau_1...\int d\tau_N \quad prob(t,\{\tau_j\}|{a_j}) \\
&=&\int d\tau_1...\int d\tau_N \quad prob(t|\{a_j\},\{\tau_j\})\cdot \prod_j prob(\tau_j)
\end{eqnarray}$$
where I have made the assumption that the priors of any two scale parameters are independent of each other and independent of the amplitudes.

**Assigning the Prior Distribution**

For the prior distribution of the scale parameter I assume knowlegde that $\tau_j \in [\tau_j^{min},\tau_j^{max}]$ but otherwise complete ignorance, which is (I think) expressed by using the Jeffreys Prior, i.e.

$prob(\tau_j)=ln(\tau^{max}_j/\tau^{min}_j)\cdot 1/\tau_j$ for $\tau_j \in [\tau_j^{min},\tau_j^{max}]$ and $0$ otherwise.

The $ln(...)$ term I have included for normalization.

**Revisiting the Marginalization Integral**

Since the prior distributions are normalized to $1$, they only contribute when integrating over terms that are dependent on the specific $\tau_j$. Thus the important integrals to carry out for each term in the sum are:
$$I_j(t) := \int_{ \tau_j^{min}} ^{ \tau_j^{max}} ln(\tau^{max}_j/\tau^{min}_j)\cdot 1/\tau_j^2\cdot \exp(-t/\tau_j)$$
this becomes [(use Wolfram Alpha to check my result)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(1%2Ftau%5E2*exp(-t%2Ftau),tau)):
$$I_j(t) =  ln(\tau^{max}_j/\tau^{min}_j)\cdot \left(\frac{\exp(-t/\tau_j^{max})}{t} - \frac{\exp(-t/\tau_j^{min})}{t}\right)$$
and finally the marginalized distribution should be
$$prob(t|\{a_j\})=\sum_j a_j \cdot I_j(t)$$

**My Question**

My question is simply: is this correct?
I do not trust the result because I cannot see the term $I_j$ converge to the original exponential in the limit that I know the scale parameter, i.e. $\tau_j^{min}\rightarrow \tau_j^{max}$.

Did I make an error in my assumptions or calculations?

Does it converge to the desired exponential after all? Or am I wrong in assuming that it should do that at all?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your integral in "Revisiting the Marginalization Integral" should run from $\tau_j^{min}$ to $\tau_j^{max}$, and there's no need for the $\ln$ term, as it's a constant so will disappear when the final constant of integration is calculated.

Comment: Thank you, I mistyped. I corrected the borders of integration. The result however was calculated using the correct borders.

Comment: Maybe you are on to something with the borders of integration. Should I try and normalize the whole integral again?  I was under the assumption that it would be fine since I merely used the product rule

Comment: @jbowman You really touched on a weak spot there.  Come to think of it: Normalization of my marginal distribution in $t\in[0,\infty]$ really seems to be the Achilles heel of my approach, because the distribution diverges at zero t. Why would that be the case? What can I do about it?

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion, and it doesn't change if you alter your prior slightly, e.g., to $\tau^{-1-\alpha}$.  I might try making the distributions of $t$ Gamma with shape parameter $a$, solve, and see what happens when $a \rightarrow 1$ (from above); the limit of the distributions may not be the same as the distribution at the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed correct, modulo a minor point, when observing a single realisation from the mixture. But not when observing an $n$-sample from the same mixture since the integrals in the $\tau_j$'s are over the product of the mixture sums, which involves $N^n$ terms, hence quickly gets intractable. The reasoning is that all the points in the sample "share" the *same* $\tau_j$'s. Hence, if
$$X_1,X_2\stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} f(x|\tau)$$
the marginal distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ is
$$\int_T f(x_1|\tau)f(x_2|\tau)\text{d}\tau\quad\text{not}\quad 
\int_T f(x_1|\tau)\text{d}\tau\times\int_T f(x_2|\tau)\text{d}\tau$$

The minor point is that the normalisation for the prior should be
$$\ln(\tau^{max}_j/\tau^{min}_j)^{-1}$$
which makes the limit of
$$\ln(\tau^{max}_j/\tau^{min}_j)^{-1}\cdot \left(\frac{\exp(-t/\tau_j^{max})}{t} - \frac{\exp(-t/\tau_j^{min})}{t}\right)$$
when $\tau^{min}_j\to\tau^0_j$ and $\tau^{max}_j\to\tau^0_j$ equal to the limit of
$$\underbrace{\dfrac{\tau^{max}_j-\tau^{min}_j}{\ln\tau^{max}_j-\ln\tau^{min}_j}}_\text{inverse derivative of $\ln(\tau)$}\cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{\exp(-t/\tau_j^{max})- \exp(-t/\tau_j^{min})}{\tau^{max}_j-\tau^{min}_j}}_\text{derivative of $\exp(-t/\tau)$}\cdot\frac{1}{t}$$when $\tau^{min}_j\to\tau^0_j$ and $\tau^{max}_j\to\tau^0_j$ hence equal to the ratio of the derivatives of the two functions of $\tau$ at $\tau^0_j$:
$$\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{\tau^0_j}}\cdot \dfrac{t\exp(-t/\tau_j^0)}{{\tau^{0}_j}^2}\cdot\frac{1}{t}=\exp(-t/\tau_j^0)\big/{\tau_j^0}$$
recovering $\exp\{-t/\tau_j^0\}/\tau_j^0$.

Note also that
$$\dfrac{\exp(-t/\tau_j^{max}) - \exp(-t/\tau_j^{min})}{t}$$
does not diverge at zero since, by L'Hospital's rule
\begin{align*}\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{\exp(-t/\tau_j^{max}) - \exp(-t/\tau_j^{min})}{t}
&=\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left[\exp(-t/\tau_j^{max}) - \exp(-t/\tau_j^{min})\right]}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{-\exp(-t/\tau_j^{max})/\tau_j^{max} + \exp(-t/\tau_j^{min})/\tau_j^{min}}{1}\\
&=\frac{1}{\tau_j^{min}}-\frac{1}{\tau_j^{max}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you a lot. Although I had the $ln(...)^{-1}$ correct in my notes, I could not see this very elegant solution. I have further questions:
* Could you elaborate on what you mean when you say that it is not OK to use this distribution as the basis of observing $n$ samples? Is it wrong to assume any two samples independent and assign the same probability distribution to them?
* Why does the distribution diverge at $t=0$? What can I do about normalization? I have tried using the gamma function instead of the exponential (as suggested above by @jbowman). Unfortunately that didn't do the trick

Comment: (ii) The density does _not_ diverge at zero, check my argument.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the part on the limit in $t \rightarrow 0$. The answer in (i) I still do not understand. Could you point me to literature where I could read up on the matter? I was under the impression that I now have a likelihood that describes the probability of observing an event at time t that incorporates my prior knowledge on the decay rates $\tau_j$. So my likelihood $prob(\{tau_m\}|\{a_j\})$ of observing a set of time points $\{t_m\}$ could be described by a product like $\prod_m prob(t_m|\{a_j\})$. I gladly appreciate any hints. Thank you again.

Comment: Again, thank you. I get it now. You completely crushed an idea that I had about tackling a certain problem, but I did learn a lot.